# Hide generated CSS content after 10 seconds

Tags: css

I have span i added  before content to the the span to create question mark icon using Font Awesome i need to hide this all generated CSS content (before) after 10 seconds using CSS code only without html code.

```
.Alert span::before{
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "\f128";
  white-space: pre;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%; 
  top: 0%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: .2s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: [Perhaps CSS animation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations) 

Answer (score 0):

Give it an animation which lasts 10 seconds and then sets display: none.

```css
.Alert span::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 30px;
  content: "\f128";
  white-space: pre;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: .2s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: disappear 10s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes disappear {
  to {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Alert">
  <span>Sme text</span>
</div>
```